# Navigation Controller - add custom nav bar item to all views

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am creating a navigation controller in my appDelegate (programmatically). I would like to add a custom button to the nav bar so that it will show up all of the views.

I can get the button to show if I add it in the ViewDidLoad methods of each controller, but is there a way I can add the button only once (i.e. in the appDelegate where I create the nav controller)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a simple hierarchy for your ViewControllers:

```
                               UIViewController
                                       |
                      CustomBarButtonItemViewController
                       /               |             \
                      /       SecondViewController    \
           FirstViewController                 ThirdViewController
```

The `CustomBarButtonItemViewController` will overwrite `-viewDidLoad`, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIbarButtonItem *barButtonItem = ...;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
}
```

Then create your `First-`, `Second-` and `ThirdViewController` as subclasses of the `CustomBarButtonItemViewController`:

```
@interface FirstViewController : CustomBarButtonItemViewController

@interface SecondViewController : CustomBarButtonItemViewController

@interface WhateverYouLikeViewController : CustomBarButtonItemViewController
```

**Make sure you call `[super viewDidLoad]` in your third-level subclasses!**

Comment: great idea.  Still, shame there isn't (that I can find) a way to do this using some sort of built in method/property/behavior on the NavController instance itself - seems like something which would be highly useful in some apps.